# Why is reloading the root page with an open secondary route throwing a TypeError "undefined is not an object getChildConfig" in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular9

I'm displaying a modal using a [secondary route](https://angular.io/guide/router#add-a-secondary-route). This works fine.

*Unfortunately, when I reload the page (or if it gets relaoded after a change in the source) with the modal open I get this error:*

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(/** @type {?} */ (route._loadedConfig)).routes') getChildConfig

This does happen only on the root page `/(test:test)`. Other routes, like `/contact(test:test)` work fine.

**What is wrong with the configuration?**

---

This is a link that opens the modal correctly:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { test: ['test'] } }]">Test</a>
```

Also closing is working just fine:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { test: null }}]);
```

The URL does look like this:

```
https://localhost:4200/(test:test)
```

*…and reloading this URL fails.*

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="test"></router-outlet>
```

This is the **app-routing.moduile.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TestComponent } from './modules/test/components/test/test.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/homepage/homepage.module').then(m => m.HomepageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/contact/contact.module').then(m => m.ContactModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent,
    outlet: 'test'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Is this happening will all urls or just this?

Comment: This happens only on the homepage /. Other routes work fine, like `/contact(test:test)`. I've updated the question. Thanks, @GouravGarg.

Comment: I faced to the same problem... It's seems to be related to this issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10726
...opened 4 years ago...